# filter by name in search bar in (swift) not working?

Tags: swift, search, filter

extension TableViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    searchedPets = PetsList.filter { $0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased() }
   
    //.uppercased()
    searching = true
    TableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I get this error: Value of type 'HomeData' has no member 'lowercased'
//notation HomeData is my data that is stored in my array

Comment: That makes sense. You need to access the property you want to filter on from your type HomeData. Something like `$0.name.lowercased()...`

Comment: Note that whenasking questions you should add all relevant information to the question instead of adding comments to your question.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson .. thanks a lot .. that's working by your answer